# #define or #if statement error

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

I have read many definitions of # if and # define statement.
I tried to use the way I read, but only with the error "**Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression**" on the line that defines it as a comment below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define is_ipad         (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define is_ipad_hd      ( (is_ipad == 1 && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width > 1024 ) ? YES : NO)
#define is_iphone_hd    ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width > 480 ? YES : NO)
#define device_width    480.0f
#define device_height   320.0f

#if (is_ipad_hd == YES) // Error here
  #define device_width       = 2048.0f
  #define device_height      = 1496.0f
#endif
```

Why it works in simple tutorials and when we try something more complex these things happen!

Comment: Preprocessor directives are evaluated before compilation; so clearly they can't operate on run-time information.  (I don't know Objective C, but `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` sounds like a run-time thing...)

Comment: Ok, now I understand.
So how do I specify the device's screen size?

Sorry my slowness, because some research techniques in English is hard to translate and look the way I imagine it should be.

Answer (score 5):

These are preprocessor directives, so you don't have access to [UIScreen mainScreen] methods and all other objects that are defined upon compilation!

Answer (score 1):

Macro evaluation happens at compile time.

However, `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` or `[UIScreen mainScreen]` can only be interpreted at run time.

Beyond that, you should not be relying on the screen size to do your dirty work for you.  You should instead be relying on the user interface idiom and the scale of the main screen:

```
BOOL isiPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
BOOL isHD = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0;

if (isiPad) {
  if (isHD) {
    // retina iPad
  } else {
    // non-retina iPad
  }
} else {
  if (isHD) {
    // retina iPhone/iPod touch
  } else {
    // non-retina iPhone/iPod touch
  }
}
```

Comment: So I would like to set it once, so I wanted to use # define and # if.
Well I do not know whether it is feasible to use a simple header, as your example, and process in every scene.

If this is right what I'm talking about.

thank you

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but would not be wrong all the time to check and set the variables at all times?
There is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with others here although I'm not as well versed in the C preprocessor a quick googling came back with this:

expression is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent restrictions. It may contain....
much better formatting than I can quickly achieve here on the [**source**.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC32)